# apply d3.nest rollup to nested pie chart (to vary the size of the pies)

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, nested, rollup

I'd like to modify Mike Bostock's nested pies example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305337
to have different pie sizes per the number of flights in each airport;  to have a visual idea of how busy each airport is. My guess is to sum up the 
number of flights via 
.rollup(function(leaves) { return {"total_flights": d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return +(d.flights);})} })   (from http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)
and apply it somehow to r (radius) but as I'm still learning, I don't know where to inject it.

Appreciate your tips/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object w/ each origin's total flights:

```
var totalFlights = {};
airports.forEach(function(d){
  totalFlights[d.key] = d3.sum(d.values.map(function(d){ return +d.count; }));
});
```

Size the arcs based on their origin's total flights:

```
 var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(function(d){ return totalFlights[d.data.origin]/952 * r / 2; })
    .outerRadius(function(d){ return totalFlights[d.data.origin]/952 * r; });
```

952 is a bit of a magic number here, set equal to the max number of flights from an airport. Ideally, you'd use a scale instead.

Working example:
http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/6471631

Comment: Thanks, Adam, it worked. For the max (magic number), I guess this should work:  

var totalFlights = {};
var maxflights = 0;
airports.forEach(function(d){
  totalFlights[d.key] = d3.sum(d.values.map(function(d){ return +d.count; }));
});
 if ( totalFlights[d.key] > maxflights ) { maxFlights =  totalFlights[d.key] };

Comment: BTW, while it worked, not sure why rollup (with its summing feature) isn't used in your solution. Can you explain?

Comment: A roll-up would add information to the origin level, but each slice is being drawn w/ the carrier level. Using a roll up would also be possible if this line was modified: '.data(function(d) { return pie(d.values).innerRadius(d.totalFlight/2).outerRadius(d.totalFlights); })